# Setting doesn't work when I open emacs in remote server

Tags: shell, emacs, package

First, I open my emacs, and use M-x shell.

Then in the shell, I type `ssh **@****`

Third, I use scp to transfer my `.emacs.d` folder into my remote home directory.

Fourthly, I type `emacs`

It opens in the shell.
But all the package don't work. Why? Thank you very much.

BTW: `init.el` instead of `.emacs` in `.emacs.d` directory

Comment: Instead of running Emacs inside a `*shell*` buffer inside Emacs I recommend investigating [TRAMP](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/TrampMode) for remotely editing files, or at least skipping the local Emacs (simply `ssh` from a regular terminal instead of from `*shell*`). Your way is very awkward, and with nested Emacs sessions keybindings could get tricky.

Comment: @Chris Thank you very much, Now I choose your second way. Open terminal, login and then type `emacs`. It will show `emacs -nw` in my terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I find my answer finally.
In generally, in my home directory, it has a file called `.emacs`
Just delete it. Then you will get what you want.